# m2eclipse/svn project with packaging of pom

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have a project with the following layout

```
taac
* taac-web
* taac-backend-api
* taac-scheduler
```

all of this is checked into an SVN repository.  When creating a new project in eclipse (originally) I checked out the root taac directory, and it gave me the option to select each of the sub-projects to create new eclipse projects for.  I had a problem with svn and had to remove the projects from eclipse, and now when trying to check them out, i no longer get this option.  If I select just the sub-projects, then their pom's are invalid (due to not having the parent pom).... Does anyone know how to get that option to select each separate project out?

Answer (score 0):

You can get entire project hierarchy into Eclipse using "File / Import... / Maven Projects" wizard or you can checkout as Maven projects from SVN (make sure you have Maven integration for Subclipse or Subversive installed).

You can also install parent's project pom into a local Maven repository, so Maven and Eclipse will be able to find it when building or working with individual projects.

Comment: was using subclipse, but switched to Subversive... seems that Subversive doesnt auto detect svn projects? There is also no option to import or check out a maven project form svn (Subversive installed)